# Get WPF control value to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Currently, I'm having a problem to pass the value of a control to my viewmodel.
This is the textbox that I want to pass to my viewmodel file.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxGenre" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
        Text="{Binding DDvd.Genre.GenreId, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

I can access it in my code behind from the XAML file, but the XAML file is linked to a viewmodel, and I want to get the value in there. How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't you do that by accessing `DDvd.Genre.GenreId` in your viewmodel?

Comment: Are you sure that the DataContext is correct? And is the object you want to bind to a public property and not a field?

Comment: I want to update my DDVd object. In that object there is a Genre object. The Genre object has a Genre ID. I am editing the genre ID a textbox, but when I want to update my DVD object, I have to find my Genre, I can do that with his ID, but I have to get the numerical value of the ID out of the textbox before I can turn it into a genre and then pass it to my DVD object